# Prove that, for any two positive integers $x$ and $y$, the value of $x \pmod y$ equals $x$ or is less than $ \frac{x}{2}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started by taking three cases viz $x<y$, $x=y$ and $x>y$. The proofs for the former two cases were pretty easy but I can't figure the same out for the remaining case. I have an intuition but it isn't too solid for formal proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First case $ : x<y$

$$x\mod y =x$$

Second case $ : x=y $

$$x\mod y =0$$

Third case $ : x>y $

$$x=ny+r \; with\; 0\le r <y \; and\; n\ge1$$

$$\implies x< (n+1)y$$
$$\implies x<2ny $$
$$\implies \frac x2 < ny$$
$$\implies \frac x2 < x-r$$
$$\implies r < \frac x2$$
$$\implies x\mod y < \frac x2$$

Comment: Sir, I couldn't understand the implication x ≤ 2ny. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @AbhinavRawal $n\ge 1 $ thus $ n+n\ge 1+n$.

Comment: @AbhinavRawal Is it Ok, or should i clarify.

Comment: I've understood, sir. I was a little confused whether there will be any case where r is exactly = x/2. Turns out there isn't, right? One can easily argue if r<x/2 then r ≤ x/2.

Comment: @AbhinavRawal Yes . Thank you for your message.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>y$: you can say $x=yq+r$, where $q$ is the quotient in division of $x$ by $y$.

We can see that $q\ge 1$ (as $x\gt y$), and $r=x\mod y$ is the remainder in that division, so $0\le r\lt y$.

Now we have $x=yq+r\ge y+r\gt 2r$, therefore $r\lt x/2$.

Comment: Shouldn't r be less than or "equal" to x/2? Or is the question statement incorrect?

Comment: @AbhinavRawal If it is always less, then you can argue that it is also always "less or equal". I hope, with a bit of luck, that I've proven a slightly stronger statement than requested in the question, that is!

Comment: So there won't be any case where r is exactly x/2?

Comment: @AbhinavRawal Unless I am somehow mistaken in the above proof, no, there won't be such a case.

Comment: There won't be any case where r is exactly equal to x/2. I solved it using the gint inequality just now.

Answer (score 0):

If $y\geqslant x$ then clearly the claim is true.
Otherwise assume that $x=ay+b$ form some non-negative integers $a,b$ such that $y\geq b$. Then for the sake of the contradiction assume that $b\geqslant x/2$. Then, $ay$ is less than or equal to $x/2$ and so is $y$ itself. Then we will have $b\geqslant (x/2)\geqslant y$ but this contradicts $y\geq b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let$$r \equiv x \pmod y$$
If $y > x$, clearly $r = x$. Now, assume $y < x$. Then
$$r \equiv x \equiv \underbrace{x - \left[\frac xy \right]y}_{<y} \pmod y$$  So, what we need to prove is $$r=x - \left[\frac xy \right]y \le \frac x2 $$or$$ \left[\frac xy \right]y \ge \frac x2$$
Since $x - 1 < [x] \le x$, it is enough to show that
$$\left(\frac xy - 1\right) y \ge \frac x2 $$or$$ xy - y \ge \frac x2 $$or$$ y \ge \frac {x}{2(x-1)}$$ which is obvious since $$\mathbb N \ni y > \frac 12 \ge \frac {x}{2(x-1)}$$